# Referencing a non-static class member in a static function

Tags: c++, static, member

so I've got something like this:

```
//somewhere in the class header 
static void bar(); 
Someobj baz;


//meanwhile in the implementation
void foo::bar()
{
   baz.f()//this doesn't work b/c baz isn't declared as static
}
```

Do I have to declare everything I want to use in the static function foo as static also or is there a better way?

Comment: static methods are non-instance methods (i.e. there is no implied "this" pointer), so calling an instance method from within a static method cannot be done.  You could pass in a pointer or reference to your class as a parameter to your static method, and call non-static methods via that parameter.

Comment: @franji1: A very common misconception -- instance methods certainly can be called from with a `static` member function, by using the `.` member access operator on an object.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is incorrect, because this present title question was misleading. Voting for reopenning.

Comment: Alternative duplicate: [non-static and static data and functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631610/non-static-and-static-data-and-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do. If you have 10 objects and they each have their own `baz`, then how is `bar` supposed to know which `baz` you're talking about?

It can't. That's why you can only have one `baz` as well, a static one.

Answer (score 0):

Static functions are like global functions, there is no associated instance with them so you cannot refer to an instance member. If you need a single baz object associated with this class make it static also. Otherwise, you need to change your logic.

Comment: How would I change the logic?

I'm working with opengl and it is the display and reshape functions are both static by nature how would adjust for that?

Comment: If your static method can take parameters, have it pass the proper baz as a param.  Anything else and you need some global way to access it.

Comment: You could pass the baz as an argument, but then perhaps you need to make bar an instance function. You could also make baz static. Or, you can make bar a standalone function.